# How to set distance value of geodistance filter from elasticsearch storted data

Tags: elasticsearch

I have to set distance value from content stored in eslaticsearch database inside the field address.radius.

distance only accept distance value when i tried to set "address.radius" I got an error.

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
        {
            "nested": {
                "path": "address",
                "filter": {
                    "geo_distance": {
                        "distance": "address.radius", // How to set address.radius in kilometer
                        "location": {
                            "lat": 48.873452,
                            "lon": 2.3522219
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
    }
}}
```

Obviously it's works when i set "distance": "25km" for instance.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `distance` parameter only accepts a specific [distance expression](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-distance-query.html#_options_4) (`25km`, `10mi`, etc), which can be expressed with [various distance units](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#distance-units).

So, it's not possible to specify a field for the `distance` parameter. What `geo_distance` queries do is to retrieve documents whose `location` is within the specified distance (e.g. `25km`) of the specified location (e.g. `48.873452,2.3522219`)